# Using over-sized image as header -- How to maintain centered image on horizontal resize

Tags: html, css

I'm essentially trying to design my header and footer how it's done at [StoreEnvy](http://www.storenvy.com/.).   They have a large (2400px wide) header and footer, which are always centered.  When you resize the page horizontally, th same part stays centered, but new parts of the image are exposed along the end of the browser window.

I've tried setting up my document like this, but I can only either 1) Get the image the resize to fit the entire window, or 2) have scroll bars totaling the width of the images.

ANy idea what I may be missing??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the image a CSS background and center it. Then it will crop as expected. There are other methods but this is the easiest.